# 14.04 - screen not locking?

Tags: 14.04, unity, lock-screen, screensaver

running 14.04.3 with unity. Since some days, occasionally my screen will not blank and lock; although "brightness and lock" is configured to exactly do that after 3 minutes.

I checked for answers here, but couldn't find anything helpful. And no, I really like the blank unity stuff; so I don't want to install x screensaver (and I never had x screensaver installed on this system).

Comment: Are you sure you're not just bashing the desk and jogging the mouse?

Comment: Well, I get up, leave the room, and nobody is close to the mouse/keyboard in the first place. And it happens in different locations, too (as long as I dont have my personal poltergeist following my laptop  and moving my mouse while I am out for my break)

Comment: And are you leaving any specific applications running? Do you have a buggy mouse that sends ghost clicks / keyboard that sends ghost keys? I.E. Can this problem be reproduced with those removed / different devices?

Comment: Different mice in different places; also different applications (I think)

Comment: Hmm okay. Just thinking that (e.g. Music player) might keep it awake. Let me have a think for a bit.